# Show that for any two nodes a and b, the unique a–b path in T has maximum capacity among all a–b paths in G

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Let G = (V, E) be a connected undirected graph and let c : E → $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ assign positive capacities to the edges. For any path P, define the capacity of P to be the minimum of the capacities of the edges traversed by P. If P has length 0, we set the capacity to be $+\infty$.

Let T = (V, F) be a spanning tree of G with maximum total capacity. That is,  $\sum_{e∈F} c(e)$ is maximized.

**Question:** How do I show that for any two nodes a and b, the unique a–b path in T has maximum capacity among all a–b paths in G? I've tried this exercise for some hours now, but I can't even figure out where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Among all paths contradicting the claim, pick one that has the minimal number of non-tree edges. Conclude that it has exactly one non-tree edge. Adding this edge and removing a lower capacity edge along the path in $T$ produces a better tree

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How do you conclude that the one with the minimal number of non-tree edges has exactly one non-tree edge?